# Fetching data from YouTube API with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, youtube-api

I am trying to populate a page with the playlists on my YouTube channel. I am using React 16 with hooks.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import PageHeader from '../components/PageHeader'
import axios from "axios"

const Tutorials = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({items:[]})
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await axios(
        'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&key=[API_EXISTS_AND_TESTED_IN_POSTMAN]'
      );
      setData(results.data.items) 
      console.log(results.data.items);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [data])

  return (
    <div className="">
      <Container>
        <PageHeader title="Tutorials" />
        <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4">
          {data && data.map(item => {
            return(
              <Col xs={12} lg={4}>
                <Card  className="bg-dark">
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{item.snippet.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      {item.snippet.description}
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            )
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tutorials
```

Here is what I am getting. However, if I delete the .map() entire function and render and then paste it and render, it will show. So the connection is happening. But as soon as I refresh, I get this. What gives? I thought maybe the data needs time to load, so I put the `setData()` in a setTimeout and also checked to see if the data is available before I try to render it and nothing worked. Postman shows my data coming back. YouTube, by the way doesn't provide an array back. It returns an Object.
[image: Screenshot 1]

I am also getting a 403 which I am not sure if it's related
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you get the error

First you setup state with a default value:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ items:[] })
```

This sets `data` to `{ items: [] }`, an object with a property named `items`, that has an array as its value.

Then your component renders and runs this line:

```
data && data.map(item => {
```

But `{ items: [] }` is not an array, and so it does not have a `map` method. This is where that error comes from.

Then after that render you update the state from an effect:

```
setData(results.data.items)
```

This (probably) sets `data` to an array, which is a different format than your initial default value for the state.

---

### How to fix the error

You either want to use an array as the default:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

Then your other code should work fine.

**Or**

you want to use the `items` property when you read/write your state.

```
setData({ items: results.data.items })
```

And something like:

```
data.items.map(item => {
```

---

### useEffect hook dependencies

Lastly, this will cause an infinite re-render cycle:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await axios(
        'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&key=[API_EXISTS_AND_TESTED_IN_POSTMAN]'
      );
      setData(results.data.items) 
      console.log(results.data.items);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [data])
```

`data` is declared as a dependency of this effect, but this hook writes to `data`. So this effect will cause itself to re-render, ad infinitum.

However, this effect does not actually depend on `data`, so it can be omitted. In this case an empty array `[]` should be used as the effect dependencies the effect does not actually use any local variables or state.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are initialising the state data as an object

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({items:[]})
```

and when the component makes the first render it tries to map an object which is not possible. So you should initialise the data state as an array:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

Also the {data && ...} is not necessary since data is an array which is a  truthy value.

The second problem in the code is with the useEffect because you have data as a dependency and you are setting the data inside the useEffect which could cause the useEffect to be called again. The correct way is an empty array as second argument:

```
  useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  const results = await axios(
    'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&key=[API_EXISTS_AND_TESTED_IN_POSTMAN]'
  );
  setData(results.data.items) 
  console.log(results.data.items);
}
fetchData();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize it with an empty array instead of an object

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```